# What does this code snippet do in detail?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

This was part of a problem in my textbook. I can't figure out exactly what it does and how it does it so I've come for help.

```
int a = 5, b[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int *ptr1, *ptr2;
void *ptr3;
ptr1 = &a;
ptr2 = b;
ptr3 = (int*) &ptr2;
```

I don't understand this line

`ptr3 = (int*) &ptr2;`

My best guess is that `ptr3` is assigned to be a int pointer that now points to the same address that `ptr2` points to right now, which is the array `b`. So basically `ptr3 = b`.

Is this correct? Can someone explain?

Comment: Why not try gdb (or some debugger).

Comment: @cnicutar To be honest, I have no idea which textbook. Why do you ask?

Comment: @noobie_programmer Because it looks rubbish.

Comment: "I have no idea which textbook. " -- And yet it's in your textbook? That makes no sense. Why should we even believe that you have transcribed the textbook accurately? `ptr3 = (int*) ptr2` makes sense; the code you provided does not.

Comment: OT: SO doesn't deal well with people changing their handles, so it's a bad idea to pick one that you're sure to want to change some day.

Answer (score 4):

`*&ptr2` gives you the address of the pointer `ptr2`. While `ptr2` points at the same location as `b`, i.e.  the address of the first int in that array, `ptr3` will point at the location of `ptr2` where the address in `b` is stored. This means it becomes an `int**` at that moment.

Sort of like this, although be careful, ptr2 and b have the same value but are distinct in memory:

`ptr3 -> ptr2 -> 1,2,3,4,5`

```
           `b /^`
```

Then the code goes on to cast that to an `int *` for reasons, that don't really make sense and that is used in the assignment to the `void *` declared `ptr3`. Looks rather wrong to me. Wherever you found it, forget about that source.

Comment: " it becomes an int** at that moment." -- This is not a good way to think of things. Simply note that the type of `&x` is `<type of x>*`, so since the type of `ptr2` is `int*`, the type of `&ptr2` is `int**`. This is a strictly static (compile-time) concept; there's no "becoming" involved.